# Errors when Trying to copy an existing screen and build it

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica v22R1, I'm trying to copy an existing screen (Business Accounts), give it a new screen ID and name, and modify it.  After doing this, and changing the references in the .ASPX and code-behind to match the new screen ID, I add it to a customization project and try to publish it.  The errors I get are related to an invalid path it's looking for in the .ASPX looking for *.inc files.  For example:

```
<!--#include file="~\Pages\CR\Includes\ContactDetails.inc"-->
```

First thing I try is to just remove this line from the .ASPX. When I publish, Acumatica puts this line back in and it fails again. The error is looking for files in a different path --

```
C:\Program Files\Acumatica ERP\Customization\<instance>\<instance>Validation\<instance>Website\Pages\AK
```

This path is apparently generated during publishing. The "AK" on the end is the screen id prefix we use for custom screens. After the validation errors are thrown, I look in this location, and indeed the files it's looking for aren't there. I also tried to copy them there manually from the CR path, but of course they get wiped out automatically when Acumatica publishes and regenerates these folders.

Any ideas what I can do to resolve or get around these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by copying all of the referenced *.inc files from the CR pages folder to my custom AK pages folder, then include them in the customization project. And also modify the .ASPX to change the path of these .inc files to my custom folder. The publish then leaves it alone and I can now build without error.